# cell.textlabel.text not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifire";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *makingString_fromArray = [appDel.Rhymes_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *datatwoParts_Array = [makingString_fromArray componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [datatwoParts_Array objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    // Assign our own background image for the cell
    UIImage *background = [self cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
    cellBackgroundView.image = background;
    cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
    return cell;
}
```

In my tableview, only first cell data show, others empty cell.i also NSLog the the array , data is there on each index but not show in the cell.
Only first cell data show.Thanks for help

Comment: please show your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method

Comment: @KIDdAe good catch there. deleted my answer as it was not the problem

Comment: Is `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` only getting called once?  Or for each item in your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        if([datatwoParts_Array count]!=0)
    return [datatwoParts_Array count];


 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you returning the count as,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [datatwoParts_Array count];
}
```

Also change the following line of code

```
cell.textLabel.text = [datatwoParts_Array objectAtIndex:0];
```

as.

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [datatwoParts_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**EDIT:**

Your code is little bit confusion, What you are trying to achieve here?

```
NSString *makingString_fromArray = [appDel.Rhymes_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *datatwoParts_Array = [makingString_fromArray componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
```

Also please share your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method

Comment: If it was a problem like this, he would have seen the same text for all his cells ...
And `datatwoParts_Array` is not a property.

Comment: @KIDdAe Understood. Thts y I mentioned tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method at first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of You.
problem is that i am getting \r\n in Stringpath, thats why text other than first cell not showing.
i used NSCharacterset to remove unused characters from string.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i found in my project and this table method i founded try to this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor clearColor]);//optional
    cell.backgroundView = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    return [datatwoParts_Array count];
}



 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath

 {

     cell.textLabel.text = [datatwoParts_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     NSLog(@" check the array value ======== %@",[datatwoParts_Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with the 6.1 beta.

```
cell?.textLabel?.text = [datatwoParts_Array objectAtIndex:0]
```